# vcpkg does not install cairo

Tags: visual-studio-code, cairo, vcpkg

Following the instruction in https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/README.md the command

> .\vcpkg install cairo --triplet x64-windows

produces

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * brotli[core]:x64-windows -> 1.0.9#1
  * bzip2[core]:x64-windows -> 1.0.8#1
    cairo[core,freetype]:x64-windows -> 1.16.0#9
  * dirent[core]:x64-windows -> 1.23.2
  * expat[core]:x64-windows -> 2020-08-18
  * fontconfig[core]:x64-windows -> 2.13.1#3
  * freetype[brotli,bzip2,core,png,zlib]:x64-windows -> 2.10.4
  * gettext[core]:x64-windows -> 0.21
  * json-c[core]:x64-windows -> 2019-09-10#1
  * libiconv[core]:x64-windows -> 1.16#8
  * libpng[core]:x64-windows -> 1.6.37#14
  * pixman[core]:x64-windows -> 0.38.4#2
  * pthread[core]:x64-windows -> 3.0.0
  * pthreads[core]:x64-windows -> 3.0.0-6
  * zlib[core]:x64-windows -> 1.2.11#9
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
No suitable Visual Studio instances were found
```

The further check

> .\vcpkg list

results in

```
No packages are installed. Did you mean `search`?
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: > No suitable Visual Studio instances were found

Answer (score 3):

I had to check two options in `Visual Studio Installer`

```
1. MSVC C/C++ compiler and linker
2. English language pack
```

After that It worked!
:)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Then ran vcpkg in the git CMD and had the folowing result:

> C:\Users\steve\vcpkg>vcpkg install liblzma:x64-windows-static
> Computing installation plan...
> The following packages will be built and installed:
> liblzma[core]:x64-windows-static -> 5.2.5#2
> Warning: The following VS instances are excluded because the English language pack is unavailable.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
> Please install the English language pack.
> No suitable Visual Studio instances were found

Installed the English language pack and problem was gone.vcpkg

Answer (score 0):

Question- did you install "Desktop Development with C++" ? If so, create a user/system variable VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH that points directly to the IDE location. If not, do that and that may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installed English language pack and Desktop Development C++ pack fixed my problem.