# vcpkg will not detect Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vcpkg

I am attempting to install some basic libraries using vcpkg. I am currently using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019, and it is installed to a custom location on the system (c:\apps\visualstudio\ide is the root).
vcpkg is currently cloned into my repos folder, which sits in my user directory. I followed all the install instructions to the letter, and successfully obtained the "linked" message that reads like so:

```
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.
```

However, when I attempt to install something simple, like boost (or anything), I get the following results

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    boost[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-accumulators[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-algorithm[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-align[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-any[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-array[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-asio[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-assert[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-assign[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-atomic[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-beast[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-bimap[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-bind[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-build[core]:x64-windows -> 1.75.0.beta1#1
  * boost-callable-traits[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-chrono[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-circular-buffer[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-compatibility[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-compute[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-concept-check[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#2
  * boost-config[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-container[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-container-hash[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-context[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#3
  * boost-contract[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-conversion[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-convert[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-core[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-coroutine[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-coroutine2[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-crc[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-date-time[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-detail[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-dll[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-dynamic-bitset[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-endian[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-exception[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-fiber[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-filesystem[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-flyweight[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-foreach[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-format[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-function[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-function-types[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-functional[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-fusion[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-geometry[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-gil[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-graph[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-graph-parallel[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-hana[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-heap[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-histogram[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-hof[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-icl[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-integer[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-interprocess[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-interval[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-intrusive[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-io[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-iostreams[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-iterator[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-json[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-lambda[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-leaf[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-lexical-cast[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-local-function[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-locale[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-lockfree[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-log[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-logic[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-math[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-metaparse[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-modular-build-helper[core]:x64-windows -> 1.75.0#8
  * boost-move[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-mp11[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-mpl[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-msm[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-multi-array[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-multi-index[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-multiprecision[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-nowide[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-numeric-conversion[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-odeint[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-optional[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-outcome[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-parameter[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-parameter-python[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-pfr[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-phoenix[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-poly-collection[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-polygon[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-pool[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-predef[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-preprocessor[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-process[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-program-options[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-property-map[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-property-tree[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-proto[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-ptr-container[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-python[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#2
  * boost-qvm[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-random[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-range[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-ratio[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-rational[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-regex[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-safe-numerics[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-scope-exit[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-serialization[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-signals2[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-smart-ptr[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-sort[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-spirit[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-stacktrace[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-statechart[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-static-assert[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-static-string[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-stl-interfaces[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-system[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-test[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-thread[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-throw-exception[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-timer[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-tokenizer[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-tti[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-tuple[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-type-erasure[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-type-index[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-type-traits[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-typeof[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-ublas[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-uninstall[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-uninstall[core]:x64-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-units[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-unordered[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-utility[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-uuid[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-variant[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-variant2[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-vcpkg-helpers[core]:x86-windows -> 7#2
  * boost-vmd[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-wave[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0#1
  * boost-winapi[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-xpressive[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * boost-yap[core]:x86-windows -> 1.75.0
  * bzip2[core]:x86-windows -> 1.0.8#1
  * expat[core]:x86-windows -> 2020-08-18
  * libffi[core]:x86-windows -> 3.3#8
  * liblzma[core]:x86-windows -> 5.2.5#2
  * openssl[core]:x86-windows -> 1.1.1j
  * python3[core]:x86-windows -> 3.9.2#1
  * sqlite3[core]:x86-windows -> 3.35.2
  * zlib[core]:x86-windows -> 1.2.11#9
  * zstd[core]:x86-windows -> 1.4.9
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
No suitable Visual Studio instances were found
```

That last part is particularly amusing, because *vswhere* successfully returns my installation.

Is there some configuration that needs to be set up for custom install directories? I otherwise can't seem to understand why my system wont work.

I am essentially seeing the same problem as this question [vcpkg does not install cairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643488/vcpkg-does-not-install-cairo/66977302)

EDIT: Fixed it. Creating a user/system variable VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH points directly to the instance.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, can you close this issue? Link should be at the bottom.

Comment: @MichaelSims perhaps, but what happens to the post if I delete it? Can other people on the internet that encounter this bug in the future see my solution?

Comment: I don't see any need to delete it, I would just mark it closed. Deleting it just flags it as deleted and you are still able to see it, but it is hidden from the rest of the community. It's a useful post, no sense in getting rid of it :-)

Comment: @jschneider99, what exactly did you set as the value of the VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH ? 
Should this be the path to some executable or particular folder ?

I tried to set it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
but I get the error: 
Could not find Visual Studio instance at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community